# What are the various browser data cache sizes?

Tags: cross-browser, streaming

Browsers render content after "enough" data has been received or once data stops flowing in (Content Length reached, for example).

I want to **slowly** stream data to the browser; to do this, I have to work around this data caching.

For example, instead of sending 40 bytes of JavaScript, I have to send the 40 bytes of JS followed by about **4 KB of spaces** in order to get the browser to interpret the script.

This works fine. But I don't remember where I first heard the number "4 KB" and was wondering what the true required amount is **per browser**.

I could of course write a bunch of tests to find these numbers, but I was curious if anyone has already done this work for me. I am also at a loss for what to ask the Google regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know what response size browsers need before rendering content when you flush the response early, I found these numbers [buried in a comment](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/18/flushing-the-document-early/#comment-603) in a post about flushing the document early:

```
IE: 255 bytes
Safari: 1K
Chrome: 2K
```

If you're looking into this so that you can implement streaming, you might want to look into how various [comet](http://ajaxian.com/archives/comet-a-new-approach-to-ajax-applications) implementations handle this.